# Apache2 - SSH - LetsEncrypt SSL - Certbot - Proxy - Manual Setup: How to achieve this?

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, proxy, certificates

I have a website running successfully on Apache port 80 HTTP (on a temporary subdomain).

I am following this tutorial in order to setup an SSL certificate on Apache2, Ubuntu using LetsEncrypt with certbot:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-multiple-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

The following steps have been performed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

The latest step fails with a

> not authorized

message, maybe because the site is behind a proxy and/or because **example.com** is not live yet (the DNS A and CNAME records are not set yet, as there should be a fluent change from the old host and the website is already live).

Therefore I have to setup the certificate manually *before* the DNS records are set. I have discovered that certbot has a `--manual` option: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual

I also have a **.cert** file for **example.com** from LetsEncrypt if this is more useful?

However this is where I am stuck and where I do not know how to proceed correctly (*yes I am quite of a noob to server setups*).

Can you tell me what is/are the next step(s) in order to setup this ssl certificate in a manual manner correctly?

Comment: Before I can start to answer your question, I need some clarification. What does the `.cert` file contain? A certificate for `example.com`? If so, why don't you use this certificate? Because you also need a certificate for `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certbot has three ways to validate your ownership of the domain to letsencrypt. Two of them (`http` and `tls-sni`) open a port and serve a certain piece of content (`http`) or a certificate (`tls-sni`); both of them aren't usable for you since the domain (as you said) does not point to the host where you are running `certbot`.

The third way (`dns`) and is perfect for your scenario.
To quote the `certbot` documentation:

> When using the dns challenge, certbot will ask you to place a TXT DNS record with specific contents under the domain name consisting of the hostname for which you want a certificate issued, prepended by _acme-challenge. 
>   For example, for the domain example.com, a zone file entry would look like:
>
> _acme-challenge.example.com. 300 IN TXT "gfj9Xq...Rg85nM"

And that is what you need to do. Run

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

This command should do the following:

- Ask you to create a DNS TXT record
- Acquire the certificate as soon as you created the DNS TXT record
- Place the certificate in `/etc/letsencrypt`

Finally *you* have to add the certificate configuration to your webserver.